# Наложение картинки на картинку при наведении

Tags: html, css

Нужно что бы при наведении на картинку сверху накладывалась еще одна?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Поместите картинку, которая должна появляться, в отдельный `div` и задайте ей `z-index` больше той, над которой хотите ее вывести.